# Finding well-posed variational form for contour shape optimization

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, variational-calculus

In a given physical problem near resonance, it is required that two energy terms, $\iint_{A} [f(x,y)]^{2}dxdy$ and $\iint_{A}[g(x,y)]^{2}dxdy$, in the system under consideration be almost equal. In other words, their difference should be minimised. Here, the integrals are performed over a surface area $A$ (simply connected) within the $xy$ plane, enclosed by a simple contour (border) $\Gamma$, while $f,g$ are two continuously differentiable eigenfunctions which were found from the system's PDE and boundary conditions over the planar domain $\Omega$ that is slightly larger than $A$  (that is, $A\subset \Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$). $f,g$ are given and are typically separable harmonic functions (such as $\sin(k_{n}x)\cos(k_{m}y)$, etc).

Our task is to find the optimal $\Gamma$ contour shape that will make the difference between the two terms minimal.

This naturally suggests a variational setting, with the functional (to be minimised) defined as

$$ J(x,y):=\int_{t=0}^{2\pi} \left|f^{2}(x(t),y(t))-g^{2}(x(t),y(t))\right| x_{t} y_{t}dt,$$

or as

$$ J(x,y):=\int_{t=0}^{2\pi} \left[f^{2}(x(t),y(t))-g^{2}(x(t),y(t))\right]^{2} x_{t} y_{t}dt,$$

where it was assumed that we can express the simple contour parametrically as ${x(t),y(t)}$, with parameter $t\in[0,2\pi]$, $x_{t}=\partial x(t)/\partial t$ and $y_{t}=\partial y(t)/\partial t$, and the square power version (second equation above) is preferred to avoid working with modulus operators, while also ensuring making zero-difference as the target for minimisation.

From a physical perspective, this integrand ($[f^{2}-g^{2}]^{2}$) should turn out to be convex and over a bounded domain, so there should be some class of contour shapes that satisfy this problem (i.e. existence + uniqueness), and I would like to use the Euler-Lagrange equation to find them. The area $A$ can be actually constrained (if needed to help uniqueness and convexity) to be fixed area $A=A_{0}\subset\Omega$, since we are interested here in the contour shape only $\Gamma$, rather than its enclosed area.

However, working with the overall squared power version of the integrand (that is, $[f^{2}-g^{2}]^{2}$) is rather difficult in practice, and I am looking for other valid forms to pose this problem so that calculations may be easier to perform analytically in closed-form.

Any suggestions?